# Auth0 /oauth/access_token obtain refresh_token mobile app?

Tags: facebook, react-native, auth0, refresh-token

I'm using Facebook SDK in my React-Native mobile app and I manage to get a token that I exchange with Auth0 on [`/oauth/access_token`](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#social-with-provider-s-access-token) to retrieve an `id_token` that I can use as `jwt` to authenticate with my API.

The problem: that endpoint doesn't return a `refresh_token` which is vital for a mobile app in order to not ask the user to authenticate every time.

How can I obtain an Auth0 `refresh_token` in order to not have the user to login every single day to Facebook and to the entire process again?

Unfortunately I can't use `Auth0 Lock` for the login UI because the React-Native version doesn't support custom UI at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not documented but you can ask for a `refresh_token` on the `/oauth/access_token` endpoint adding `offline_access` in the `scope` and a `device` name.

```
request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: `https://${AUTH0_URL}/oauth/access_token`,
  data: {
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    access_token: FBToken,
    connection: 'facebook',
    scope: 'openid profile email offline_access',
    device: 'mobile phone',
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the current documentation here: https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/preview/refresh-token#get-a-refresh-token

According to the documentation you should get a refresh token after requesting `/oauth/access_token` as long as you include the `offline_access` scope in your original request.

If that's not the case, I would bug support.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as stated here https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/preview/refresh-token#get-a-refresh-token the endpoint that is accepting `offline_access` is not `/oauth/access_token` but `/oauth/authorize`

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to do the original request to get the token?

Comment: You may want to look into using https://github.com/auth0/react-native-lock
with https://github.com/auth0/Lock-Facebook.iOS as well